# How do I fill an image within a grid area in CSS grid. Below is the code

Tags: html, css, css-grid

```css
.container1 {
  width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin: 0.2em auto;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:25% 25% 25% 25% ;
  grid-template-rows:25% 25% 25%; 
  grid-template-areas:"image1 image2 image3 image3"
                       "image4 iamge4 image5 image6"
                       "image7 image8 image8  image6"
}
   
.image1 {
   grid-area: image1;
   /*
   grid-column-start:1;
   grid-column-end: 2;
  */
   border:0.75em black solid;
   filter:grayscale(100%);
   overflow:hidden;
   object-fit: contain;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container1">

<div class="image4">
  <img src="image/image4.jpg" alt="journey map" />
</div>
<div class="image5">
  <img src="image/image5.jpg" alt="wireframing-low fidility" />
</div>
```

I am trying to fit the image into the grid area, I tried object-fit: contain, cover ..almost everything but it isn't happening.

update:removed the grid-column-start and grid-colum-end

Comment: Why are you adding **both** `grid-area` AND `grid-column/row` properties. Pick one...not both.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Add the demo to the **question** not in comments.

Comment: Hi Paulie , updated the code ...the image is not resizing though

Comment: @VisakhViswam you refer to `container1` and `image1` in your provided CSS, but your HTML contains no `container1` div, nor an `image1`... please update your code

Answer (score 2):

Going based off of your provided code and your comments, i've made a fiddle which may or may not solve your problem:

HTML:

```
<div class="container1">
  <div class="image4 image">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2d/Google-favicon-2015.png/150px-Google-favicon-2015.png" alt="journey map" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container1 {
  width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin: 0.2em auto;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:25% 25% 25% 25% ;
  grid-template-rows:25% 25% 25%; 
  grid-template-areas:"image1 image2 image3 image3"
                       "image4 iamge4 image5 image6"
                       "image7 image8 image8  image6"
}

.image {
   grid-area: image1;
   /*
   grid-column-start:1;
   grid-column-end: 2;
  */
   border:0.75em black solid;
   filter:grayscale(100%);
   overflow:hidden;
   object-fit: contain;
 } 

 .image img {
   width: 100%;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6xspyrs7/1/

by adding the CSS on the `img` tag itself, it resizes the image according to its container